# Every when to handle/check facebook errors (android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Ok I have Facebook integrated in an app however there are [some issues](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#whattodoerror) to bear in mind.

Token has expired, app revoked etc...

My idea is to make a http call to the `/me` in the graph and if i do not get an error, continue. However if I make this call every time the user opens the app it will slow down the launching time, right? My problems are in user experience.

1. So if my assumption above is correct, I have to make an interval (like a day) to check that for the next 24h the user can use the app without making this http request. Store in the memory when the app checked and if reopen "have a free pass". Is it a good strategy?
2. In the case of token expiration (which I assume they last 60 days) would it not be annoying to logout the user and ask him again to login?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make a request to /me or /me/permissions to see if the user has revoked specific permissions, if you do this in the background, then it shouldn't affect the launch time. Alternatively, you can have a generic error handler that handles all FB request failures, and deal with any access token errors there.
2. If you use the Request class in the Facebook SDK to make your requests, and the FB app is installed on the user's device, then it will auto-extend your tokens when they're about the expire. If the FB app is not installed, then you'll have to re-login the user.